# Teaching logic and problem solving to children?

Tags: education, learning, homeschooling, gifted, problem-solving-skills

We have all been there, "Critical Thinking: Solve why blah blah blah" in our elementary and high school assignments.  We've all hated them to death, but I think sometimes we see the value in these things a little bit later in life.

Today I'm a software developer and inventor.  I make things and solve problems for a living and I look back regretfully that I did not understand the true nature of the questions earlier in life that faced me in school.  I had this realization the other day while helping my 8th grade son with his algebra questions.  I was able to see the context of this now and explain to him why these questions are important, even though the school, teachers and government miss the boat.  I explained to him that the TEST MAKERS' goals are to help people learn and to evaluate how well we can solve logic problems that require us to think freely and figure out how to solve problems out of the box.  Like I said, this is all lost in translation with all of the government stipulations, etc…

But, I got to thinking that I'd really like to help my children learn how to think properly about problems.  In this case I instructed my son to *always* draw a picture first of any problem he faces and to delineate the things that he knows about the problem or situation.  We are visual creatures and we have to have pictures, not just text, to help us visualize things.  With this ability, I explained, he will be able to solve **any** problem that he faces, at least in academia and in the intellectual worker world.

After that experience, though, I felt the need to find more challenges or puzzles for him and my other children to solve.  Things that will help in both cognitive and common sense development hopefully.  The problem I'm having is that I'm not really readily finding any resources that will help in this venture.

***Is anyone familiar with some not-too-boring and contrived exercises or such that could be useful in helping children by giving them practice at solving problems in a wide range of scenarios both analytically and perhaps socially?***

I realize that this might be a steep order, but I the epiphany that I had really has me feeling an acute need for helping them in this regard so that it doesn't take them another 10-20 years to start seeing things in context.

Comment: My answer summarized: I conclude, based on what you write that you act out of **regret** which raises a fear. Your fear is that your children will miss out on something if you do not stimulate their problem solving. Regret and fear aren't proper motivators.

Comment: I would remove the 'we are visual creatures' bit - it often isn't true...

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I disagree.  We are all indeed visual creatures.  There's no way around it.  We base all life and social interaction on this.  That is what language has been developed for and stems from; an abbreviated and concise form for describing the world (visual / contextual) around us.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Actually it is my own fear of not doing enough.  One thing for which I am exceptionally grateful is that there is no fear in our household.  I have been able to maintain wonderful relationships with all of my four children without evoking fear and regret.  On the other hand, I leverage my own examples of regret to them so as to illustrate that it is better to learn these things from others' experiences vs "hitting the wall" themselves or going through the pain of experience.  Sure, many of us learn through experience, BUT we can often learn by proxy.

Comment: @ylluminate Your motivation, partially constructed of regret and fear, as you say yourself, is inferior to a more constructive motivation that would not involve regret and fear. Its not about what you do, its the motivation that matters. Its the motivation that defines the 'quality' of the action. You may have to accept a bit more that each being has its own path of progress, tasting a pudding through proxy seams impossible to me. None the less I wish you and your children the best, as that's the motivation behind my answer and comments.

Comment: Well I think you're off base quite a ways here & reading a tremendous amount of "stuff" into your assumptions / assertions. I guess it's simply a lack personal context of the situation & my words may be lacking to explain it all to you, but c'est la vie.  My true motivation is to see them reach maximum potential out of a deep and eternal love for my children, wanting them to maximize this mortality so that they can enjoy the fruits of a deeper and richer world to come.  So ultimately my motivation always boils down to love, even though other things promote and prompt realization & recognition.

Comment: I think Mike is completely correct here - I have taught many hundreds of individuals over the years, at all ages from toddlers to 40+ and one definite point: everyone is different, with their own motivators. My own kids would not respond well to anything like 'draw a picture of the problem' - it is entirely alien to the way they work. Work with your children to find out what they respond best to, **then** use that technique. You will find it helps a lot.

Comment: @RoryAlsop They all work amazingly well with pictures.  :) I have also taught well over 1,000 students in my career and pictures (diagrams, renderings, chicken scratch on napkins, etc.) have never failed me or my professors many years ago.  I have a background in education and computer science as well as parents who were both elementary and college professors.  Pictures have always been key for all of my experiences, especially with abstract concepts.  I'm sorry our experiences diverge, but hey, it is what it is. ;)

Comment: Regarding your most recent edit: unfortunately, [questions focused on receiving specific product recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are off-topic.  Please consider editing that part back out, as asking for general strategies is much more appropriate than requesting tangible resources.

Comment: @Beofett unfortunately this is a very big negative aspect of SO and apparently all SE exchanges.  I'm really disappointed to hear that as we need tangible actionable recommendations that go beyond generalities.  How can you get specifics unless you ask for specifics?  Otherwise the usefulness is cast into the wind here…  I have tried to express this same concern to others, but it seems to be ignored, downplayed or simply laughed at.  What is one to do -- seriously, should I look into making a new SE that is more flexible and realistic for peoples' needs?

Comment: The reasons why these types of questions are generally viewed as a poor fit for the SE platform are pretty well outlined in that blog entry by one of the founders. However, please note that we've [opened the subject up to the community](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/432/can-we-alter-the-site-rules-to-allow-questions-that-seek-reference-material), and did not see any consensus that the community feels the rules should be changed for parenting.se. Feel free to cast your vote(s) on that discussion, as the issue is still open.

Comment: @ylluminate"there is no fear in our household",so you are all enlightened spiritual beings then,why ask questions here?And how come you can speak for others?You can't.You may think of fear as "I'm afraid of the neighbor and I can tell you why if you ask me" kind of fear,but that is not the fear I talk about.I am talking about the profound fear,that is hiding behind a seemingly reality created by illusion.Now that fear isn't obvious and takes tremendous effort to track down,and even more effort to overcome.Saying your family members do not experience fear,is delusional on itself.

Comment: @ylluminate "Well I think you're off base quite a ways here" That is because you do not (want to?) understand my point.How can you categorize information *off base* if you do not understand the meaning?And you clearly don't understand, or else you wouldn't say stuff like "there is no fear in our household" as that is very unlikely.Don't be stubborn and try to maintain an open mind."simply a lack personal context of the situation" has nothing to do with it.Yes growing up (spritiualy) is personal yes.But the way to do it,no,thats a general way,for all of us: partially overcoming fears.

Comment: @ylluminate"So ultimately my motivation always boils down to love".So your love is partially constructed from fear and regret?As those are still present within you,and partially motivate your action. That doesn't seem ultimate love to me. You are fooling yourself, not willing to see (and overcome) that hard to track down fear. It seems more easy to solve it externally (teaching your children logic),then it to solve it internally:growing your self up spiritually.The same pattern arises with the cause of a problem: Its easier to blame someone else,than to track down the problem within yourself.

Comment: @ylluminate One can only grow up to the extend of ones own will.That is the nature of consciousness,and that is the way it should be.You are an individual.If someone else could grow you up,you are no longer an individual,but you would be part of that someone else.Now do you want to grow up more?Then welcome all information.Do not think you are grown up,simply because you have reached a certain age or have children.You can always improve yourself and that is growing up.Now be honest,do you want to understand my point (and be able to judge the info given yourself),or do you prefer to ignore it?

Comment: I know I'm late, but introduce them to Basic, Gamemaker or Scratch. The goal of making a game will provide motivation, the final game is the reward - no matter how basic. If I had been introduced to the technology to program games when I was younger I'd probably know 15 programming languages by now rather than my meagre 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"We are visual creatures and we have to have pictures, not just text, to help us visualize things."

I'd be a bit careful about that idea.  Not everyone thinks the same way.  In fact, people have a [variety of learning styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_styles), and most people find that one or two styles of learning may be more effective for them than others.

You may want to suggest a variety of strategies, such as the drawing strategy you suggested, and let your son decide for himself which of the strategies work best.  He may find that drawing is helpful for some problems, but other strategies might be better for other problems.

However, to address your primary question:

> Is anyone familiar with some not-too-boring and contrived exercises or such that could be useful in helping children by giving them practice at solving problems in a wide range of scenarios both analytically and perhaps socially?

It sounds like what you are looking for are word problems of the type I know as "brain teasers".  These are generally text-based scenarios, frequently described as real-world problems, that call for analytic thinking that helps teach children to break out of the complacent modes of thought we sometimes wind up in.

In some cases, they provide the bare minimum of information to solve problems through rather complex deductive reasoning.  Other times they provide "red herring" details that seem relevant, but aren't.

Some examples:

"There are two barbers in town.  One has a great haircut, and a sparkling clean shop. The other has a bad haircut, and his shop is worn and dirty.  Which barber do you ask to cut your hair?" Answer: the barber with the bad hair cut.  Since you can't cut your own hair, the barber with the bad hair cut must have given the good hair cut to the other barber.

"A boat has a ladder over the side.  At low tide, three rungs of the ladder are submerged in water.  The rungs are evenly spaced twelve inches apart.  As the tide comes in, it causes the water to rise at a rate of 3 inches per hour.  In four hours, how many rungs will be submerged?"  Answer: 3. As the water rises, so does the boat.

"Because cigars cannot be entirely smoked, a hobo who collects cigar butts can make 1 cigar out of every 5 butts that he finds. Today, he has collected 25 cigar butts.  How many cigars can he smoke?" Answer: 6 (not 5).  He makes 5 from the 25, then smokes them, and gets 5 more butts, allowing him to make a sixth cigar.

These are just some fairly easy examples that I remembered off the top of my head.  However, there are more involved brain teasers that require careful analysis of all the details.  These can range from complex algebra to deductive logic, and require a variety of analytic strategies to solve them.

Generally, I find them to be more fun than the standard problems, and they are varied enough to teach a number of different concepts.  If you search for "brain teasers" online, you should be able to find a lot of options.

Comment: I'm not sure about brain teasers. My dad loved them and posed them to us a lot, but neither my siblings or I enjoyed them one bit. All of us kids went on to critical thinking career fields, too.

Comment: @justkt When it comes to teaching/learning, I'm strongly of the belief that there's no single "ideal" approach.  I enjoyed brain teasers as a child, but not everyone will.  Similarly, some people actually enjoy straight algebra problems. However, brain teasers does seem to me like a good match for what the OP is asking for.

Comment: +1 I always loved brain teasers, and joined Mensa quite young - and the problem solving skillset is 100% related to most of what I have done with my career so far. Visually drawing out a problem doesn't help me at all - although I do it for others who have a visual bent...

Comment: A lot of brain teasers *don't* encourage people to think critically (IMHO).  Look at the two barbers example.  It doesn't say there aren't more than two barbers - a town with 10 barbers also has 2 barbers.  It doesn't say anything about travel in or out of the town.  It precludes the idea that people can cut their own hair (they can!).  It doesn't mention if the town had hair dressers or stylists or if the barber's hair was 'natural' or synthetic.  But, given just those few lines of text, we're concluding that the barber with bad hair *MUST* have done something.

Comment: @RobP. Those brain teasers were drawn from my memory from when I learned them almost 30 years ago. They were not intended to be exactly verbatim, but rather to give the general idea. I'm quite sure that the original did explicitly mention that the two options were the *only* two in town, and probably addressed some of the other details. Don't use my failing memory as an indication that most, or even some, brain teasers discourage critical thinking by providing insufficient data.

Comment: @Beofett - I don't mean to seem like I'm attacking you or one specific riddle.  My point was that many are meant to be entertaining or clever and are not concerned with being 'correct' in any exhaustive or absolute sense.  I found many retellings of the 'two barbers riddle' and none of them provided enough details to support the answer.  (http://www.bigriddles.com/riddle/the-two-barbers) - that's not to say there aren't riddles/puzzles that are more concrete.  I just find that a good percentage are more arbitrary than anything else.

Comment: @RobP. I agree the quality of brain teasers can vary quite significantly, as can the types of thinking they (supposedly) encourage. I just wanted to clarify that my examples were drawn from distant memory, and weren't intended to be fully representative of complete brain teasers.

Comment: Beofett, great, so you propose to teach our kids how to make cigars out of cigar butts? Might as well teach 'em how to make moonshine while we're at it! :)

Comment: @ATS That was an actual problem I was given... I believe in Elementary school.  Yet oddly enough I didn't start smoking cigars until almost 30 years later.  One would hope that we'd simultaneously be teaching our kids that cigars made out of cigar butts **just aren't as good at the real thing**!  Now, if I had known how to make moonshine, it would have made me really popular in high school... Although I'm pretty sure there's a "reality" show airing now that explains how to not only make moonshine, but the entire business of smuggling, distributing, and selling it.

Answer (score -3):

I sense a bit of overreaction here, and unbalanced behavior.
Please read to the end, and then decide what you will do with the information in this answer.

Your kid is probably a left or a right brainer (as 99% of the people are). Either his brain prefers to think logically, or his brain prefers to experience emotion and he behaves accordingly.

If he is more of the emotional side, you might bring him a bit more in balance by stimulating his analytical thinking. But that would require your emotional feedback. You will have to give him the feeling that what you are doing helps him to become more balanced. Otherwise he feels like what you are trying to teach him is less important than what he prefers: emotion. And that might even make him distant more from your perspective. Which is totally the opposite of your goal: prepare your children to function autonomously.

If he prefers logic more (like you do, so it seems), you are over stimulating him, bringing him further away from balance. Only a balanced mind gives best direction to its own life by setting the right goals.

I would strongly suggest you start 'listening' to your own feelings more, and become more balanced yourself. This balance is passed on to your children naturally. The opposite is true as well, if you are out of balance, you pass that on to your children as well.

**EDIT 2:**
An example of how to listen to your emotion could be like this:
How do I feel about all this, putting a topic on the net, asking for help to stimulate the logical problem solving of my kid? I would say that you feel some sort of stress, based on what you say: " really has me feeling an acute need for helping them in this regard."
Now if it feels like stress, why doing it? Now I am not asking for an answer that you can give within the blink of an eye. What is your profound motivation? I would say its **regret**: "I look back regretfully that I did not understand". And thats a negative emotion. Regret isn't constructive. Regret can make you grind to a stop (like in making progress in life). Now it probably isn't that much of a deal for you, it doesn't takes over your life. Now compare regret to motivation that comes from the emotion of love. You see the difference? So do you want to give your children direction based on regret?
*End of edit 2*

If I am correct, and you prefer logic more (you are a programmer so you don't deal much with emotion in your profession), you probably think: "What the **** is this for an answer, this is not what I am looking for".

Your logical side of the brain has to accept that the emotional side is worth 50% of the 100% available decision space to give your life direction. If you THINK otherwise (the logical analyses), you shut the door for the input of your own emotion, and even worse, you naturally, by your **unconscious** behavior, negate the emotional side of your children. Unconsciously, because this can never be a conscious choice of a well willing parent.

This might seem totally exaggerated, and that is exactly the viewpoint of an unbalanced brain. If you do not think this is exaggerated, than you are probably very open minded or you are in balance (enough) already.

Try to view the value of this answer from the two perspectives (logically and emotionally) as an exercise. If you can't, you have, by definition, a profound preference for either one of the perspectives.

What I like to mention is that I am a professional software developer myself, I have wife and two children.

Whatever you may think of this answer, I sure wish you the best.

**EDIT 3:**
You have used the phrase "so that it doesn't take them another 10-20 years to start seeing things in context.". Thats the focus of a mind that is not in the **NOW**. A balanced mind isn't busy with the past (regret puts your focus in the past), and isn't busy with future problems. A balanced mind experiences the moment of now with joy. Now I can almost be sure that you think "But you will have to look a head to guide things into the right direction". That is not true. Future problems do not exist, but become problems of the present moment instantly when you start thinking about them. A balanced mind that experiences joy in the moment of now will not run into problems as he makes the right decisions on the moment its necessary.
*End of edit 3*

**EDIT:**
I know I did not gave you an answer on the question where to find material to educate logic and problem solving to your children. That is, because I think your motivation is 'wrong'. If you would have stated it sort of like this, I would have tried to help:
My kid tends to get caught up in his feelings, not knowing a way out. His feelings in certain situations aren't what you call 'real' (as defined in reality). For example, when he has a problem, he doesn't know how to solve it. He tries to do other things to make him feel well again, but as long as he can't put it in perspective, he tends to stay stressed. I think he could be helped if he would be able to put his problems in perspective more and work towards a solution by analysis instead. What would be a good training to help him stimulate the logical problem solving more?

Comment: I agree, and additionally I would also point out that even assuming one does want to foster a super-logical brain in one's children, forcing a visualisation of the problem isn't necessarily the best way either - not everyone has a visual learning style, and while for some people that would be great, for others it would make no sense at all.

Comment: "Future problems do not exist, but become problems of the present moment instantly when you start thinking about them" - great, I'll cancel my pension payments then!

Comment: @JamesBradbury You just proofed the quality of your being, with sarcasm being the lowest form of wit. Now start working to improve the quality of your being instead of wasting your time with useless sarcasm. How does your statement compare to the selfless effort I put in answering this question? I pity your short sightedness. As you are a software engineer yourself (probably prefering logic), I understand you do not understand the 'blabber' about emotions yourself.

Comment: My sarcastic comment had a serious point. Would you like to address it?

Your answer contained little useful information, but much vague philosophising and veiled ad-hominem attacks suggesting that anyone who disagrees is "out of balance". Hence the down-vote.

Comment: @JamesBradbury "My sarcastic comment had a serious point" which is totally missed... "contained little useful information", information is only present if the interpreter is capable of interpreting it, so you could better have written: "I think your answer contains little useful information". How can philosophy (which contains the definition of "based on logical reasoning") be vague? Logic is only vague if the interpreter isn't capable of comprehending the logic. "Attacks"? Do I try to destroy, being hostile? No I am not.

Comment: @JamesBradbury `that anyone who disagrees is "out of balance"` isn't what I stated, thats your conclusion. I gave thought experiments to determine yourself whether you should stimulate the emotional side. But still, whats your addition to the solution of the askers problem? You haven't added anything. You are trying to destroy (attacking?) my answer, without superseding it with logic. Your criticism is mostly vague and does not address single point of my answer with precision. If you disagree,do it with content. e.g."I disagree with your edit 2 that his motivation comes from regret because.."

Comment: @JamesBradbury `"Future problems do not exist, but become problems of the present moment instantly when you start thinking about them" - great, I'll cancel my pension payments then!` So you consider it a problem as well that you have to eat and drink to give your body energy to move in future events? That you consider your pension payments a problem isn't what defines reality. It defines your way of thinking.

Comment: Hmm, my "I agree" comment above was made before edit2 and edit3, which I think have lowered the quality of the answer overall. Just for the record.

Comment: @JamesBradbury Now disagree with logic with the comment I put beneath the askers question. I am eager to learn how one can disagree on that.

Comment: Please avoid prolonged discussion in comments; comments are intended for clarification and improvement of the answer.  If you need to discuss this at length, please take it to [chat]. However, I would advise everyone to tone it down a notch. Insults do not belong here or in chat.